# Terminal find Command: Manipulate Output String

Tags: string, bash, terminal

I am trying to manipulate the filename from the find command:

```
find . -name "*.xib" -exec echo '{}' ';'
```

For example, this might print:

> ./Views/Help/VCHelp.xib

I would like to make it:

> ./Views/Help/VCHelp.strings

What I tried:

```
find . -name "*.xib" -exec echo ${'{}'%.*} ';'
```

But, the '{}' is not being recognized as a string or something...

---

I also tried the following:

```
find . -name "*.xib" -exec filename='{}' ";" -exec echo ${filename%.*} ";"
```

But it is trying to execute a command called "filename" instead of assigning the variable:

> find: filename: No such file or directory

Comment: I edited answer to explain why you can't simply use `-exec filename='{}' ";"`, please make sure you read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use *Parameter Expansion* with literal string. Try to store it in a variable first:

```
find . -name '*.xib' -exec bash -c "f='{}' ; echo \${f%.xib}.strings" \;
```

`-exec` sees first argument after it as the command, therefore you can't simply give it `filename='{}'` because `find` doesn't use `sh` to execute what you give it. If you want to run some shell stuff, you need to use `sh` or `bash` to wrap up.

Or use `sed`:

```
find . -name '*.xib' | sed 's/.xlib$/.strings/'
```

Comment: Perfect, I wanted to understand why my trials failed. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, your first method fails miserably if a file name contains a single quote.

Comment: Also, try to `touch $'lol.xib\nnotfunny.xib'` and see what happens... here both methods fail miserably. I hope this will not be used in production scripts.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf If there is really a production environment for allowing those characters in filenames, then just save a script `echo "${1%.xib}.strings"` and run with `-exec ./script '{}' \;`.

Comment: @livibetter yes! or you can use globstar and get rid of the `find` altogether for such simple searches.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The OP was asking `find`, but please do post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple search, you can use a pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

found=( **.xib )

for f in "${found[@]}"; do
   echo "${f%xib}strings"
done
```

Turning the `globstar` shell option on enables the `**` to "match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories" (as quoted from the bash reference manual). The `nullglob` option helps if there's no match: in this case, the glob will be expanded to nothing instead of the ugly `**.xib`. This solution is safe regarding filenames containing funny characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.xib" | sed -e 's/\.xib$/.strings/'
```